# How can I obtain the Oauth2 access token for the FrontEnd from Backend?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I am working on a Java project using Spring Authorization Server. My question is, how can I authenticate users with either credentials or Google for the frontend, which is separate and built with React? Should I expose the form to the frontend, or is there another process?

I'm using spring boot 3.

My config is this:

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainForServer(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(c -> c.defaultSuccessUrl("/time", true))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }
```

The form is functioning correctly, but I am unsure if exposing the OAuth2 login form is the appropriate flow for a separate frontend and backend.

Comment: Please share any code you have working, as well as add some details to this question to describe your desired outcome or current challenge.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I added my http config code

Comment: I'm still not able to understand your question. "Should I expose the form to the frontend, or is there another process?" feels like an opinion-based question, but it's possible I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Can you please elaborate and explain your use case in more detail, or rephrase the question if it is opinion-based?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg isn't an opinion, I want to know if the correct flow for oauth2 is to expose the login form to the FE

Comment: Please explain your use case in more detail. I'm not sure I know what's meant by "expose the login form to the FE" in the context of the frontend being a React app because the login form is a server-side rendered page. For example, are you asking "Is it correct to *redirect* to the login page from the react app in order to perform the authorization code flow?"

Comment: Did you happen to see my question above?